# Providing specialized initializers for a generic struct

Tags: swift, generics, struct

I have a simple generic struct defined - its only requirements is that its stored properties be `Comparable`:

```
struct Bounds<A: Comparable> {
    let lower: A
    let upper: A
}
```

However, I'd like to provide a couple of specialized initializers for the struct, which would use some math operations to set up the properties.

```
    init(value: Double, tolerance: Percentage) {
        self.lower = value * ( 1 - tolerance )
        self.upper = value * ( 1 + tolerance )
    }

    init(value: Measurement, tolerance: Percentage) {
        self.lower = value.value * ( 1 - tolerance )
        self.lower = value.value * ( 1 - tolerance )
    }
```

The result should obviously be two different structs, where A is a `Double` or a `Measurement`.

But how do I do this?

I can't provide specialized init methods in the definition as the compiler will complain that `Double is not convertible to A`. OK...

I can't provide the init methods in individual extensions constrained by specific types (`where A == Double`) as the compiler complains:

> Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'A' non-generic

Maybe I should be using a protocol to which both `Double` and `Measurement` conform in initialization, but that seems odd, since the `Bounds` struct should just care that they both conform to `Comparable`.

I feel like I'm either missing something really simple, or trying to do something really misguided with generics. Which is it, SO?

Comment: How are `Percentage` and `Measurement` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but a possible workaround (Swift 3):

```
extension Bounds where A: FloatingPoint {
    init(value: A, tolerance: A) {
        self.lower = value * ( A(1) - tolerance )
        self.upper = value * ( A(1) + tolerance )
    }
}

let b = Bounds(value: 4.0, tolerance: 0.1)
print(b.dynamicType) // Bounds<Double>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict your generic more strongly, to access in-protocol blueprinted methods for transforming e.g. a `Double` value to the type of the generic.

```
protocol FromDoubleTransformable {
    static func doubleToSelf(from: Double) -> Self
}

/* drawback: only types conforming to 'FromDoubleTransformable'
   will be able to be used as generic in 'Bounds' below          */
extension Int: FromDoubleTransformable {
    static func doubleToSelf(from: Double) -> Int {
        // simple example without any out-of-bounds checking
        return Int(from)
    }
}

struct Bounds<A: protocol<Comparable, FromDoubleTransformable>> {
    let lower: A
    let upper: A

    init(value: Double, tolerance: Double) {
        self.lower = A.doubleToSelf(value * ( 1 - tolerance ))
        self.upper = A.doubleToSelf(value * ( 1 + tolerance ))
    }
}

let foo = Bounds<Int>(value: 120, tolerance: 0.1)
print(foo.dynamicType)      // Bounds<Int>
print(foo.lower, foo.upper) // 108 132
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are performing operations on types where that operations have not been defined.

E.g.

```
value * ( 1 - tolerance )
```

The operation `-` between `Int` and `Tolerance` where is defined?

This is how you can fix it

```
protocol BoundsType: Comparable {
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    var prev: Self { get }
    var next: Self { get }
    init(double: Double)
    init<M:Measurement>(measurement:M)
}

protocol Percentage {
    associatedtype BoundsType
    var toBoundsType: BoundsType { get }
}
protocol Measurement {
    associatedtype BoundsType
    var toBoundsType: BoundsType { get }
}

struct Bounds<A: BoundsType, P:Percentage, M:Measurement
              where P.BoundsType == A, M.BoundsType == A> {
    let lower: A
    let upper: A

    init(value: Double, tolerance: P) {
        self.lower = A(double:value) * (tolerance.toBoundsType.prev)
        self.upper = A(double:value) * (tolerance.toBoundsType.next)
    }

    init(value: M, tolerance: P) {
        self.lower = A(measurement:value) * tolerance.toBoundsType.prev
        self.upper = A(measurement:value) * tolerance.toBoundsType.next
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this is Martin R.'s "workaround." The issue here is that `Comparable` does not have any of these math operations defined on it, or even any guarantee that it is a numeric type at all. It could just as easily be a string, or an array, or any other type that implements `Comparable`.

So, yes, you must write extensions constrained to either a common protocol that implements these operators or to the concrete types in question. For example:

```
extension Bounds where A: FloatingPoint {
    init(value: A, tolerance: Percentage) {
        self.lower = value * ( 1 - tolerance )
        self.upper = value * ( 1 + tolerance )
    }
}
```

Or, if `Measurement` does not conform to `FloatingPoint`:

```
extension Bounds where A == Measurement {
    init(value: A, tolerance: Percentage) {
        self.lower = value.value * ( 1 - tolerance )
        self.upper = value.value * ( 1 + tolerance )
    }
}
```

Also, since you probably don't want to use any non-numeric types for your bounds then I would define it as something along these lines:

```
struct Bounds<A: Numeric & Comparable> {
    let upper: A
    let lower: A
}
```